# Adding fractional parts.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Let $x, y, z \in \{0,\frac{1}{2018},\frac{2}{2018},...,\frac{2017}{2018} \} $. Prove that $$\{\{x+y\} +z\} =\{x+\{y+z\} \} $$, where $\{\} $ denotes the fractional part.
I don't really know how to approach this, I tried to use the definition of the fractional part, but it didn't help. I have also observed that $\{x\} =x$ for any $x$ in that set, but I don't know how to use this.

Comment: This amounts to $((x+y)\bmod n+z)\bmod n=(x+(y+z)\bmod n)\bmod n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that for any real $x$ and integer $n$,

$$\{x+n\}=\{x\}.$$

This implies that for any reals $x,y$,

$$\{x+y\}=\{\{x\}+\lfloor x\rfloor+y\}=\{\{x\}+y\},$$ and symmetrically.

From this,

$$\{\{x+y\}+z\}=\{x+y+z\}=\{x+\{y+z\}\}.$$

This property is more general than what you have to prove.

Answer (score 2):

We have succesively:

- $\{x+y\}$ differs from $x+y$ by an integer.
- $\{x+y\}+z$ differs from $(x+y)+z=x+y+z$ by an integer.
- $\{\{x+y\}+z\}$ differs from $(x+y)+z=x+y+z$ by an integer.

And the same happens on the other side. So:

- $\{y+z\}$ differs from $y+z$ by an integer.
- $x+\{y+z\}$ differs from $x+(y+z)=x+y+z$ by an integer.
- $\{x+\{y+z\}\}$ differs from $x+(y+z)=x+y+z$ by an integer.

So the numbers $\{x+\{y+z\}\}$  and $\{\{x+y\}+z\}$ are in $[0,1)$ and differ by an integer. They are equal.

---

Alternative proof:

The given relation is the associativity in $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, expressed in terms of using representatives in $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have that
$$\begin{align}
\{\{ x+y\}+z\}
&=\{-\lfloor x+y\rfloor +x+y+z\}\\
&=\{ x+y+z\}\\
\end{align}$$
and similarly you can write
$$\begin{align}
\{ x+\{y+z\}\}
&=\{-\lfloor y+z\rfloor +x+y+z\}\\
&=\{ x+y+z\}\\
\end{align}$$
Hence the two are equal for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$.